# TreeView is not syntax highlighted

Tags: qml, qt5, qt-creator, qtquick2

Qt Creator 5.5 doesn't syntax highlight `TreeView` both in Windows and MacOS.

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: Screen.width /2
    height: Screen.height/2

    TreeView {
        anchors.fill: parent
    }

}
```

`TreeView` is marked red underlined as if not recognized by Qt Creator but it does compile and run fine. Why is it not syntax highlighted properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's a bug, because the required modules are properly imported.

You can suppress the warning using `//@disable-check M300` before the line `TreeView {`

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: Screen.width /2
    height: Screen.height/2

    //@disable-check M300
    TreeView {
        anchors.fill: parent
    }

}
```